Attach files on Trello using c#
I would like to attach a list of files on Trello using c#.
I'm using TrelloDotNet.Model to interact with Trello web.
I've already created a list and a card but I don't know how to attach the files to the created card.
Do you have some ideas?

Have you tried using AddAttachmentToCardAsync?

could you provide your existing code.

@Kwiksilver yes, but then I'd need to use "AttachmentUrlLink" wich attach the link of where the file is not the file it self. This way, only I can acces the file because it's in my computer

public static async Task FillTrello(ProjectVM projectVM)
{
var APIKey = "-";
var Token = "-";
var client = new TrelloDotNet.TrelloClient(APIKey, Token);
var board = await client.GetBoardAsync("-");

string listID = "-";

var description = projectVM.Name + "\r\n" + projectVM.Data + "\r\n" + string.Join(" / ", projectVM.MaquinasSelecionadas) + "\r\n" + projectVM.Setor + "\r\n" + projectVM.Descricao;


var card = new TrelloDotNet.Model.Card(listID, FolderName, description);
var newcard = await client.AddCardAsync(card);

}

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Hi. As you can see, it's quite hard to read the code when it's placed in the comments like this. Stackoverflow isn't like a standard discussion forum (see the [tour] for more info). Comments are only used for brief clarification. Your question has an [edit] button under it, which you can use to improve the main post, then the information is visible, all in one place, and can be formatted properly. To allow us to consider your code fully, please edit your question and place it there. How do I format my posts? may be useful to read as well. Thankyou.
